# JSON remove multiple duplicate keys in Java

Tags: java, json

I have come across a situation where I need to parse a JSON string and if the string contains multiple duplicate keys, I'd have to make a list of those keys that have been duplicated. For instance,

```
{
   "a":1,
   "b":2,
   "c":{"a":1, "z":2},
   "b":"blah",
   "c":34
}
```

So in the above example, my List would contain 'b' and 'c' as keys that have been duplicated. Note that 'a' would not be in this list, as even though it exists twice, it resides in the value of 'c'.

When I call `new JSONObject(jsonString)` processing stops after the first duplicate key has been found, but I want ALL the duplicate keys to be found.

I have tried multiple methods, but I face the old problem of fixing one issue and hence creating a second issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I apologize, I should have mentioned this earlier. **I have to search for duplicate keys in Java and return a list of keys that have been duplicated**

Comment: That's not a valid JSON object, so most libraries I'd assume won't work well with it.

Comment: How is it invalid? Besides the duplicate keys

Comment: hashtable and chain on duplicates, implementation is up to you.

Comment: @CollinD RFC4627 specifies "The names within an object SHOULD be unique.". So it is a bit borderline if this is valid JSON or not. (Most implementations would say it's not).

Comment: Just to clarify, my web service will be receiving the JSON as a string from a POST request and the JSON may be incorrectly formatted to include duplicate keys. So I have to parse this JSON in Java and return a list of all duplicate values found

Comment: @Henry That's good to know. I've seen conflicting reports but never bothered reading the RFC. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a special object to convert json string to this class by jackson ObjectMapper. based on the attribute type, string will be converted to suitable attribute. You should set following properties to ignore invalid attributes :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

but for finding duplicated attributes, you should convert input to [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) object and execute a for loop for finding duplicate keys.